# FiniteArrayQueue type with interface and unit tests

Tags: java, array, queue, circular-list, junit

Doing some exercises on basic data structures, I learned about queues, and decided to roll my own to better understand how a basic queue can function. As the name indicates, this Queue is made from a finite (i.e. regular) array. The JavaDoc gives more details throughout.

All this is pretty new to me, so I'm hoping to receive criticism on any and all aspects that can be improved.

#### Interface & Exceptions:

```
public interface Queue {
    public int getSize();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public boolean isFull();
    public void enqueue(Object obj) throws QueueFullException;
    public Object dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException;
}

public class QueueEmptyException extends RuntimeException {
    public QueueEmptyException() {
        super();
    }
    public QueueEmptyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public QueueEmptyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}

public class QueueFullException extends RuntimeException {
    public QueueFullException() {
        super();
    }
    public QueueFullException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public QueueFullException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

#### FiniteArrayQueue

```
/**
 * A FiniteArrayQueue can enqueue 0..N Objects, after which it must dequeue Objects to make room to enqueue
 * more Objects. Objects may be dequeued from it until the queue is empty. The size of the queue cannot be changed
 * after instantiation.
 */
public class FiniteArrayQueue implements Queue {
    private Object[] queue;
    private int capacity;
    private int head;
    private int tail;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * <p>
     * Note that in order for a FiniteArrayQueue to have a "true" capacity of N items,
     * its array size must be of (N + 1) to account for not being able to overlap
     * the head and tail pointers of the queue (unless the queue is empty).
     * @param desiredCapacity : The maximum number of items that can be in the queue
     */
    public FiniteArrayQueue(int desiredCapacity) {
        capacity = desiredCapacity + 1;
        queue = new Object[capacity];
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    /**
     * Indicates whether the queue is empty.
     * <p>
     * Note that when the head and tail are at same index, the queue is empty.
     * @return boolean : true if queue is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return(tail == head) ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * If the head is one index higher than the tail, the queue is full.
     * <p>
     * Note that the 2nd condition is added to "wrap around" the array in case
     * the tail is at the last index and the head is at index 0.
     * @return boolean : true if queue is full
     */
    public boolean isFull() {
        int diff = tail - head;
        if(diff == -1 || diff == (capacity - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * The current size of the queue, i.e. the number of items present in it.
     * @return int : the size of the queue
     */
    public int getSize() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (tail > head) {
                return tail - head;
            }
            return capacity - head + tail;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Add/insert an Object at the tail index (or "back") of the queue, if the queue is not full.
     * <p>
     * Note modulo operator is used to "wrap around" the array.
     * @param obj : The object to add/insert at the tail index
     */
    public void enqueue(Object obj) throws QueueFullException {
        if(isFull()) {
            throw new QueueFullException("Queue is full.");
        } else {
            queue[tail] = obj;
            tail = (tail + 1) % capacity;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Removes the Object at the head index (or "front") of the queue, if the queue is not empty.
     * <p>
     * Note modulo operator is used to "wrap around" the array.
     * @return obj : the object at the head index
     */
    public Object dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException {
        Object item;
        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new QueueEmptyException("Queue is empty.");
        } else {
            item = queue[head];
            queue[head] = null;
            head = (head + 1) % capacity;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

#### FiniteArrayQueueTest

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * Unit tests for FiniteArrayQueue.
 */
public class FiniteArrayQueueTest extends TestCase {
    private static final int CAPACITY = 4;
    private Queue testQueue;

    public FiniteArrayQueueTest(String testName) {
        super(testName);
        testQueue = new FiniteArrayQueue(CAPACITY);
    }

    public void testIsEmpty() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(testQueue.isEmpty());
    }
    public void testNotIsEmpty() throws Exception {
        testQueue.enqueue("Hello");
        assertFalse(testQueue.isEmpty());
    }
    public void testIsFull() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
            testQueue.enqueue(i);
        }
        assertTrue(testQueue.isFull());
    }
    public void testNotIsFull() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            testQueue.enqueue(i);
        }
        assertFalse(testQueue.isFull());
    }
    public void testGetSize() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            testQueue.enqueue(i);
        }
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 3);
    }
    public void testEnqueue() throws Exception {
        testQueue.enqueue("A");
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 1);
    }
    public void testDequeue() throws Exception {
        testQueue.enqueue("Foo");
        assertSame(testQueue.dequeue(), "Foo");
        assertTrue(testQueue.isEmpty());
    }
    public void testGetSizeWithWrapAround() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
            testQueue.enqueue(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            testQueue.dequeue();
        }
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 1);
        testQueue.enqueue(4);
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 2);
        testQueue.enqueue(5);
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 3);
        testQueue.enqueue(6);
        assertEquals(testQueue.getSize(), 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: The call of generics compels you...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On testing...

Your tests are incomplete, certainly.

---

Your test on `isEmpty` only tests two conditions: a newly instantiated queue which has never had anything added to it should return `true`, and after adding just one thing, it should return `false`.

- How does `isEmpty` do when the queue is full?
- How does `isEmpty` do when the queue has had two items added and then one removed?
- How does `isEmpty` do when the queue has had two items added and then two removed?
- How does `isEmpty` do when it has been filled, emptied, then filled again?
- How does `isEmpty` do when our queue is instantiated with a max size of zero?

---

We can ask a lot of the same questions for `isFull`.

- How does `isFull` do with a newly instantiated queue that has never had any objects added to it?
- How does `isFull` do when we've filled it and then removed one or more objects?
- How does `isFull` do when we've filled it, removed some objects, then filled it back to capacity?
- How does `isFull` do when we create a queue with max size zero?

---

We can ask some questions of `getSize` too.  You've only tested on very specific and weird case.

- Does `getSize` return the proper value of a newly instantiated array before we've added anything to it?
- For every call to `enqueue`, does `getSize` return the correct value? (*Hint: You can `assert` in a loop*)
- If we have a full queue, try to enqueue, catch the exception, does `getSize` still return the expected value?
- For every call to `dequeue`, does `getSize` return the correct value?
- When we've filled, then emptied to zero, does `getSize` return the correct value?
- If we have an empty queue, try to dequeue, catch the exception, does `getSize` still return the expected value (zero)?

---

How about enqueuing and dequeuing?

Your `testEnqueue` is testing the wrong thing.  That's asserting that `getSize` works.

The first assertion in `testDequeue` has the right idea, but the second assertion is testing that `isEmpty` works.

Neither of these tests test that the proper exception is thrown in the proper conditions.

I would write something called `testFirstInFirstOut` that runs through lots of iterations and combinations of enqueuing and dequeuing and making sure things are coming out in the order we'd expect them to come out in.

I'd also write a test called `testEnqueueException` to verify that when we try to enqueue into a full queue, we get an exception.

I'd also write a test called `testDequeueException` to verify that when we try to dequeue from a full queue, we get an exception.

---

And most importantly, I'd spend a *LOT* of time on ***THIS*** answer before you even begin to start trying to implement any of the advice from my other answer (or any other answer that addresses anything but testing).

Refactoring has a tendency to introduce regressions.  [Unit tests prevent regressions](http://importblogkit.com/2016/01/unit-tests-dont-prevent-bugs/).  Beefing up your test suite before you start refactoring is a good way to make sure you're introducing as few regressions as possible.

Comment: Wow, no kidding. I shall start writing many more tests right away, really appreciate the sanity check and all the suggestions of things to test for

Answer (score 10):

First, a minor nitpick.

> ```
> public boolean isEmpty() {
>     return(tail == head) ? true : false;
> }
>
> public boolean isFull() {
>     int diff = tail - head;
>     if(diff == -1 || diff == (capacity - 1)) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Twice we're using returning true or false based on the result of a conditional.  Why not just directly return the result of that conditional?

- `return (tail == head)`
- `return (diff == -1 || diff == (capacity - 1))`

---

Typically, queues are implemented by being backed by a linked list.  The fact that you've used an array here is what has limited you to a particular size.  With a linked list, the only limiting factor would be how much RAM is available to the program.

Moreover, with a linked list backing your queue, items in the queue don't need to be located in a contiguous block of memory.  With your implementation, by storing them in array, it requires finding a contiguous block of memory in the system large enough to hold all of the items you'd ever want to hold.

---

Having `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods that throw exceptions *quickly* makes any code written to use this queue *very* verbose.  Essentially, all of the primary usage of the queue must be done within `try`-`catch` blocks.

By using the aforementioned linked list backing strategy that eliminates the need to put a limit on how many items, the queue never has to be full (until the program runs out of RAM, but that's an all together different problem), so we should never run into an exception when enqueuing objects.

On dequeuing objects, I feel like `null` should be the appropriate return value from an empty queue.  Whoever dequeued can be responsible for checking whether or not it got null out, and if not, risk getting a null exception.

---

You should make use of generics.

`Object` works decent enough for putting in anything... but it also means you can get anything out.  And you cannot limit what can be put in.  So, on the `dequeue` end of things, you can quickly get into a mess casting things about.

---

As long as your queue has a finite size or is backed by an array, you should probably expose a `getCapacity` method.

Comment: I agree with your answer except for the part where you advocate for returning `null` instead of throwing an exception.  Requiring someone to check for `null` is the same effort as catching an exception. Checking for `null` obfuscates the flow of your program and decreases readability, whilst exceptions can be caught at the end of your function and do not disturb the flow for the reader.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using generics.  Forcing the caller to cast dequeued results from `Object` isn't really acceptable.

The `QueueEmptyException` should probably just be `NoSuchElementException`, just like in other `java.util` classes.

The off-by-one definition of `capacity` is awkward.  I would just drop that member altogether and use `queue.length` instead.

The `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` methods should just be implemented in terms of `getSize()`.  All of those methods have too many cases.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getSize() == 0;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return getSize() + 1 >= queue.length;
}

public int getSize() {
    return (tail >= head) ? tail - head
                          : tail - head + queue.length;
}
```

In `dequeue()`, the code outside the if-else is awkward.  I'd write it this way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue is empty");
    } else {
        T item = (T)queue[head];
        queue[head] = null;
        head = (head + 1) % queue.length;
        return item;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why all of your unit tests have `throws Exception` declared.  That just squelches possible compiler errors that might be informative to you.

Comment: Thanks. On unit tests `throws Exception` those were at first added by IntelliJ and I just stuck with it, not knowing better. Would it be better in future to generally not do that, then?

Comment: @PinCrash Yeah, avoid that whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

Just a few nitpicks that hasn't been mentioned:

- Your `FiniteArrayQueueTest` does not need to `extends TestCase`, that was the old way of using JUnit. Remove that `extends`.
- Annotate your methods with `@Test` and you don't have to explicitly have `test` in their name.
- Use `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

Also, your interface specification does not need to mark methods as `public`, all interface methods are public already. So `public int getSize();` can be just `int getSize();`

Answer (score 5):

**On Fixed Size:**

I don’t think I have ever backed a queue with a fixed sized array apart from code written for university exams.   However it is easy to extend what you have done to allocate a new array of double the size and copy the item over if the queue gets filled.   Doing so tends to be faster than using linked lists on modem CPUs (due to the processor cache) and also creates lets garbage so helps the garbage collector.   See [Strategy: Stop Using Linked-Lists](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/22/strategy-stop-using-linked-lists.html)

**On Naming:**

Lets take this code for example:

```
public FiniteArrayQueue(int desiredCapacity) {
    capacity = desiredCapacity + 1;
    queue = new Object[capacity];
    head = tail = 0;
}
```

You have written nice small methods with clear names that greatly helps with understanding the code.   However it is very easy to mix up parameters that are passed into the method and fields of the object when reading the code.   Therefore it is better to prefix all your fields with “_”, so making the code read like:

```
public FiniteArrayQueue(int desiredCapacity) {
    _capacity = desiredCapacity + 1;
    _queue = new Object[_capacity];
    _head = _tail = 0;
}
```

(Some people will disagree with the above, but every programming job I have done in over 20 years of programming, we had had some naming convention for members of a object.)

Comment: I'd be really interested in seeing some evidence that using an array and doubling its size when necessary would be more efficient than a linked list...

Comment: @nhgrif, Firstly a link list takes up a LOT more space the you expect compared to an array (remember the hidden class pointer etc).   You then have to consider issues of CPU prefetching and cpu caches along with the costs to the garbage collect of having more objects.   http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/22/strategy-stop-using-linked-lists.html  gives a overview and a few links.

Comment: And how much time does it take the cpu to find a contiguous block of memory large enough for an array of a thousand elements? And then copy five hundred elements over? How about on the next double? Perhaps for small queues an array might be more efficient in a garbage collected language... But even for memory, the fact that the array needs an increasingly larger block of contiguous memory means that it will run out of space sooner.

Comment: @nhgrif,  the best option sometimes is to have a linked list of VERY large notes, where each note  is an array that can hold something like 500 items.   But that gets complex

Comment: @nhgrif,  "contiguous memory" is not an issue in most garbage collected systems, as the GC compacts the memory.    (Remember this is a JAVA question not a C/C++ question.)  If you want more details ask a question on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or stackoverlow

Comment: Well, in the end, we can at least agree that having a limited size is very strange.  An expansion of the unit tests could include some performance tests that make sure that no matter how we implement the queue, it is both working and performing to whatever our requirements are.