# MazeRunner in Java

Tags: java, queue, pathfinding

To test the queue I perfected from one of [my CR question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121637/doublingqueue-in-java)s, I've developed a maze program that receives an input maze, starting and end positions, and solves it. I have separate software that handles the maze execution and file parsing. I'm curious as to whether my implementation is optimal (fully expecting it to not be), and was wondering what could be done to optimize it.

Just for reference: I renamed my class from `DoublingQueue` to `ArrayQueue`.

**Maze.java**

```
public class Maze {

    public final static char WALL = 'X', PATH = '.';

    private static char[][] maze;

    private Location start;
    private Location end;

    public Maze(char[][] puzzle, Location startPos, Location endPos) {
        maze = puzzle;
        start = startPos;
        end = endPos;
    }

    public int size() {
        return maze.length;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size(); j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
                System.out.print(' ');
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public char mark(int i, int j, char value) {
        assert (isInMaze(i, j));

        char tmp = maze[i][j];

        maze[i][j] = value;

        return tmp;
    }

    public char mark(Location pos, char value) {
        return mark(pos.i(), pos.j(), value);
    }

    public boolean isMarked(int i, int j) {
        assert (isInMaze(i, j));

        return (maze[i][j] == PATH);
    }

    public boolean isMarked(Location pos) {
        return isMarked(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    public boolean isClear(int i, int j) {
        assert (isInMaze(i, j));

        return (maze[i][j] != WALL && maze[i][j] != PATH);
    }

    public boolean isClear(Location pos) {
        return isClear(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    public boolean isInMaze(int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < size() && j >= 0 && j < size();
    }

    public boolean isInMaze(Location pos) {
        return isInMaze(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    public boolean isFinal(int i, int j) {
        return (i == end.i() && j == end.j());
    }

    public boolean isFinal(Location pos) {
        return isFinal(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    public char[][] clone() {
        char[][] mazeCopy = new char[size()][size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            System.arraycopy(maze[i], 0, mazeCopy[i], 0, size());
        }

        return mazeCopy;
    }

    public void restore(char[][] savedMaze) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            System.arraycopy(savedMaze[i], 0, maze[i], 0, size());
        }
    }

    public void solve() {
        char[][] savedMaze = clone();

        ArrayQueue<Location> candidates = new ArrayQueue();

        Location current;
        Location next;

        candidates.enqueue(new Location(start.i(), start.j()));

        while (!candidates.isEmpty()) {
            current = candidates.dequeue();

            if (isFinal(current)) {
                break;
            }

            mark(current, PATH);

            next = current.north();

            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                candidates.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.east();

            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                candidates.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.west();

            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                candidates.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.south();

            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                candidates.enqueue(next);
            }
        }

        if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("You're stuck in the maze!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You got it!");
        }

        print();
        restore(savedMaze);
    }
}
```

**Location.java**

```
public class Location {

    private int i, j;

    public Location(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int i() {
        return i;
    }

    public int j() {
        return j;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("(" + i + "," + j + ")");
    }

    public Location north() {
        return new Location(i - 1, j);
    }

    public Location south() {
        return new Location(i + 1, j);
    }

    public Location east() {
        return new Location(i, j + 1);
    }

    public Location west() {
        return new Location(i, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### All your `Maze` belong to `Maze.maze`

The cells of the maze are in a static `char[][]`. Multiple `Maze` instances will share this, which will be unexpected and surely lead to bugs. This is especially troubling considering that the constructor takes a `char[][]` parameter, replacing the static data. So if I create a `Maze` with some data `cells1`, and another `Maze` with some other data `cells2`, both instances will use `cells2`.

#### Single responsibility principle

The `solve` method does too much:

- find path from start to end
- reset the maze
- print the completed maze
- print if path could be found

It would be better if `solve` did just that: solve the maze. All the other steps should be outside of this method.

#### Naming

`maze` is a poor name for cells. So is the constructor parameter `puzzle`.

It's confusing to use similar names for different purposes, such as `Maze` for the class and `maze` for the `char[][]` field.

It's confusing to use different names for the same purpose, such as `maze` and `puzzle` for the `char[][]` data.

With the names improved, the constructor could be:

```
public Maze(char[][] cells, Location start, Location end) {
    this.cells = cells;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

`i` and `j` are very poor names for location coordinates in `Location`.
These names are most commonly used as loop variables, and rarely appropriate for other purposes. `row` and `col` would be better.

#### What's the size of a maze?

The implementation assumes that the width and height are the same.
You could add an `assert` in the constructor to document that fact:

```
public Maze(char[][] cells, Location start, Location end) {
    assert cells.length == cells[0].length : "the width and height of the maze should be the same";

    this.cells = cells;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

A better solution would be to change the implementation to mazes where the width and height can be different. It looks easy to do.

#### Unused methods

The `isMarked` methods are unused. They were strange anyway, considering that the `mark` methods take a `char` parameter and `isMarked` don't, which begs the question: is marked *what*? In any case, as these methods are unused, they should be removed.

#### Unused return values

The return value of the `mark` method is never used. As such, this method should be `void`, and then it can be simplified.

#### Inappropriate `clone`

The `clone()` method is special in Java. It should be used only to override `Object`'s `clone()` method to avoid confusion. (However, in general, it should not be used at all. See Effective Java by Joshua Bloch for a detailed explanation.)

A propose the name `copyCells` instead. I added the "Cells" suffix, because that's the only thing that is copied, `Mace.clone` and `Maze.copy` would suggest a copy of the entire maze, returning a `Maze` instead of a `char[][]`.

And the implementation can be simplified, by using the `clone()` method of arrays:

```
public char[][] copyCells() {
    char[][] copy = cells.clone();

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        copy[i] = cells[i].clone();
    }

    return copy;
}
```

#### Incorrect use of generics

The type parameter is missing at the right hand size:

> ```
>     ArrayQueue<Location> candidates = new ArrayQueue();
> ```

Add `<>` to correct it:

```
    ArrayQueue<Location> candidates = new ArrayQueue<>();
```

#### Duplicated code

As you check each direction, you have this condition repeated 4 times:

> ```
> if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
> ```

It would be better to move this condition to a helper method, so that you can reduce the duplicated logic, for example:

> ```
> if (isPossibleMove(next)) {
> ```

#### Make `final` what can be `final`

The fields `maze`, `start` and `end` are never reassigned, so it's good to make them `final`.

#### Modifier ordering

It's a minor thing, but instead of:

```
public final static char WALL = 'X', PATH = '.';
```

The recommended ordering of modifiers is this:

```
public static final char WALL = 'X', PATH = '.';
```