# MazeRunner in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, queue, pathfinding

I've refined a lot of the code from [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123349/mazerunner-in-java), and have also decided to include the logic that interprets a given text file. Any advice on how to improve the actual algorithm that solves the maze would be appreciated! I'd also like to figure out how to store the full path to the exit in a queue.

Here's the format by which an input text file must adhere to:

```
6 6
S.X...
..X.XT
X.X.X.
..X.X.
X.....
XX.X.X
```

**Location.java**

```
public class Location {

    private int i = 0;
    private int j = 0;

    public Location(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int i() {
        return i;
    }

    public int j() {
        return j;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<" + i + "," + j + ">";
    }

    public Location north() {
        return new Location(i - 1, j);
    }

    public Location south() {
        return new Location(i + 1, j);
    }

    public Location east() {
        return new Location(i, j + 1);
    }

    public Location west() {
        return new Location(i, j - 1);
    }
}
```

**Map.java**

```
public class Map {

    ArrayQueue<String> contents = new ArrayQueue<>();

    private int height = 0;
    private int width = 0;

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    private Location start;
    private Location end;

    public Location getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public Location getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public Map(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader);

        int lineCounter = -1;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lineCounter++;

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lineCounter + ": " + line);

            if (lineCounter == 0) {
                height = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(line.charAt(0)));
                width = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(line.charAt(2)));
            } else if (lineCounter <= height && line.length() == width) {
                contents.enqueue(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public char[][] chart() {
        char[][] maze = new char[height][width];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            String line = contents.dequeue();

            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                char c = line.charAt(j);

                if (c == Maze.START) {
                    start = new Location(i, j);
                }

                if (c == Maze.END) {
                    end = new Location(i, j);
                }

                maze[i][j] = c;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Start: " + start.toString() + "; End: " + end.toString());
        System.out.println();

        return maze;
    }
}
```

**Maze.java**

```
public class Maze {

    public static final char PATH = '.', WALL = 'X', START = 'S', END = 'T', MARK = '*';

    private char[][] maze;

    private int height = 0;
    private int width = 0;

    private Location start;
    private Location end;

    public Maze(Map map) {
        maze = map.chart();

        height = map.getHeight();
        width = map.getWidth();

        start = map.getStart();
        end = map.getEnd();
    }

    private void mark(int i, int j) {
        assert (isInMaze(i, j));
        maze[i][j] = MARK;
    }

    private void mark(Location pos) {
        mark(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    private boolean isClear(int i, int j) {
        assert (isInMaze(i, j));
        return maze[i][j] != WALL && maze[i][j] != MARK;
    }

    private boolean isClear(Location pos) {
        return isClear(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    private boolean isInMaze(int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < width && j >= 0 && j < height;
    }

    private boolean isInMaze(Location pos) {
        return isInMaze(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    private boolean isFinal(int i, int j) {
        return i == end.i() && j == end.j();
    }

    private boolean isFinal(Location pos) {
        return isFinal(pos.i(), pos.j());
    }

    private void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void solve() {
        ArrayQueue<Location> options = new ArrayQueue<>();

        options.enqueue(start);

        Location current;
        Location next;

        while (!options.isEmpty()) {
            current = options.dequeue();

            if (isFinal(current)) {
                break;
            }

            mark(current);

            next = current.west();
            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                options.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.south();
            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                options.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.east();
            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                options.enqueue(next);
            }

            next = current.north();
            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next)) {
                options.enqueue(next);
            }
        }

        if (!options.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Completed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You're in Tahiti!");
        }

        System.out.println();
        print();
    }
}
```

**Main file**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Map map = new Map(args[0]);
            Maze maze = new Maze(map);
            maze.solve();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Program Output**

```
1: 6 6
2: S.X...
3: ..X.XT
4: X.X.X.
5: ..X.X.
6: X.....
7: XX.X.X

Start: <0,0>; End: <1,5>

Completed!

**X*..
**X*XT
X*X*X*
**X*X*
X*****
XX*X*X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Naming problems

### Location j and i varibles

> ```
> private int i = 0;
> private int j = 0;
> ```

Using x and y makes more sense for a location object that i and j, because x and y are also used in matrixes.

## Logic issues

### Catching exception

> ```
>    catch (Exception err) {
>        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
>    }
> ```

Catching Exception is a anti-pattern, better would be catching exceptions seperate:

```
   catch (FileNotFoundException | IndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
       System.out.println(err.getMessage());
   }
```

### Ignoring the errors of Scanner

When reading streams with a scanner, errors can happen while reading. When you are done reading, you should check for exceptions using [`ioException()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#ioException()), and rethrow as needed. Error while reading can happen if the reading happens to hit a damaged sector on the hard disk, or the file system is a remote one, and the connection gets lost.

---

## Fixing the algorithm

*Congratulations on making a implemtation of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).*

Your algorithm isn't designed properly:

- A maze needs to be closed before it can be solved in parallel, a potential heavy operation
- It doesn't return the path taken

### Working of the new algorithm

To make a better algorithm, that also has the potential to get the route back, we are going to use an implementation based on [dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). We are also going to use a `PriotityQueue` with the algorithm, so we can quickly convert our system to use the ["A* search algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for a quicker solving of the mazes.

### Coding the algorithm

To start with the system, we are declaring another `int[][]` that contains our pathfinder lengths, and a [`PriorityQueue<Location>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) that contains the nodes we still need to visit. We are also going to use a `Comparator` in combination with our `PriorityQueue`, since we want to use dijkstra's in combination with the A path find search technique.

We are now going to work on the actual solving. We first add our first node to the queue, and then we are going to use a while loop to go over the queue. For every node we visit, we look first at the neighbors, and add the to the queue if not already visited. We are then picking the lowest nonzero value from our neighbors and place it in the nodes current visited slot. then we continue with the next node.

After we filled our list of nodes, we only need to check if the route is solved, and if its solved, return the route.

### Finishing the algorithm

**Notice: ** For this algorithm to work properly, you need to add a equals to your `Location` class:

```
private boolean equals(Location pos) {
    return i == pos.i() && j == pos.j();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Location) {
        Location pos = (Location) obj;
        return equals(pos);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above steps together will produce the following code:

```
public List<Location> solve() {
    int[][] solvedMaze = new int[height][width];

    PriorityQueue<Location> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Location>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Location a, Location b) {
            double distanceA = distance(start, a) / 1.5 + distance(a, end);
            double distanceB = distance(start, b) / 1.5 + distance(b, end);
            return Double.compare(distanceA, distanceB);
        }

        private double distance(Location first, Location second) {
            return Math.abs(first.i() - second.i()) + Math.abs(first.j() - second.j());
        }
    });

    queue.add(start);

    Location current;
    int counter = 0;

    while ((current = queue.poll()) != null) {
        counter++;

        if (solvedMaze[current.i()][current.j()] != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        for (Location next : new Location[]{
            current.north(), current.south(), current.west(), current.east()
        }) {
            if (isInMaze(next) && isClear(next) && solvedMaze[next.i()][next.j()] == 0) {
                queue.add(next);
            }
        }

        solvedMaze[current.i()][current.j()] = counter;

        if (isFinal(current)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (solvedMaze[end.i()][end.j()] != 0) {
        List<Location> route = new ArrayList<>();
        Location temp = end;

        while (!temp.equals(start)) {
            route.add(temp);

            Location best = null;
            int bestVal = solvedMaze[temp.i()][temp.j()];

            for (Location next : new Location[]{
                temp.north(), temp.south(), temp.west(), temp.east()
            }) {
                if (isInMaze(next) && solvedMaze[next.i()][next.j()] != 0 && solvedMaze[next.i()][next.j()] < bestVal) {
                    bestVal = solvedMaze[next.i()][next.j()];
                    best = next;
                }
            }

            assert best != null;
            temp = best;
        }

        route.add(start);
        Collections.reverse(route);

        return route;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Printing the route in the main method:

Printing the newly generated route is easy in the main method:

```
maze.solve().stream().forEach((pos) -> {
    System.out.println(pos.toString());
});
```

You may notice that if you change the distance function used in the comparator for the queue, the generated routes will differ if passing a large flag area

#### How does this new algorithm work?

It works by keeping a `int[][]` of visited nodes, increasing the numbers as they go farther from the starting point. Because our queue automatically reorders the nodes to select the ones that are the closest to the start and end, it will generally pick the best routes. To see information about the internal routes, you can print our the contents of the internal queue with the following code:

```
        for(int[] line : solvedMaze) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
        }
```

This will show a grid, with numbers that are increasing from the start to the end. When the search reaches the end, it will follow those numbers back to the start.

Comment: So, in your second code block, why do you only use your defined `PriorityQueue` one time? Doesn't it need contents to compare? Did you mean to replace the `options.enqueue(next);` lines with `queue.add(next);`?

Comment: Yes, I meant to replace them, probably forgot to see it. There where more typo's in that last bit, [fixed them too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/123631/revisions)

Comment: Also, in the `while` condition, `(loc == queue.poll()) != null` is not a valid statement since a boolean is never null. Did you mean something like `loc == queue.poll() && loc != null`?

Comment: I put what I got from your answer in another answer to this question. One thing I still don't quite understand is `solvedMaze` multidimensional array. Am I supposed to replace all occurances of `.` with 1s or 0s? It would help me out a lot more if you just plopped what you mean in my Maze implementation.

Comment: Let me edit, I am working on a expansion, including tests and a replacement for your solve method

Comment: @T145 I have updated the code and tested it. Can you check if it works for you too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37405/discussion-between-ferrybig-and-t145).